# COMO CRIAR SITE OU FÓRUM QUE TENHA ACESSO AOS DADOS CADASTRAIS DOS USUÁRIOS

Tags: banco-de-dados

Queria saber se tem algum site/fórum que o ADM possa ter acesso aos dados de quem se cadastrar (basicamente o login e senha que usaram para criar, apenas) e que seja de fácil manuseio (sou noob em programação).

Comment: Todos os sites são assim.

Comment: Acho que ele está perguntando sobre uma ferramenta para se criar um fórum. E uma que permita acesso à senha cadastrada pelos usuários é bem ruim, além de tudo isso é uma brecha de segurança.

Comment: @Piovezan geralmente todo adm tem acesso a tudo, é como se fosse um moderador com mais privilégios ainda. Exceto senhas, a não ser que o sistema seja muito ruim mesmo.

Comment: Eu queria um algum tipo de site ou fórum fake pra quando a pessoa registrasse, eu tivesse acesso aos seus dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu quero justamente saber como se cria um site com o sistema ''muito ruim mesmo''

Comment: @Unboarding a parte do ruim me refiro só a senha, o resto ser visível ao ADM não quer dizer que seja ruim. Eu não estou falando ruim de qualidade de códigos, estou falando ruim de questões de segurança. Mas independente disso, criar um sistema com login, senha, administrador, postagens, recuperação de senha, etc, é bem amplo e não é um problema especifico de programação e nem muito menos pode se comparar a uma receita de bolo. As alternativas são, contrate um programador ou tente usar um sistema gratuito de fórum. De qualquer forma não é o que fazemos no StackOverflow...

Comment: ... Aqui as perguntas são sobre problemas específicos de programação e não sobre criar programas inteiros. Irei travar os comentários pois o foco da pergunta é totalmente OFF-TOPIC em relação ao site. Obrigado a todos por compreenderem